# Focus on or focus in?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> She focusses **on/in** developing the four language skills.

Which preposition is the correct one to use? Do was focus *on* something, or focus *in* something?

Answer (score 1):

One focuses ON something.

> focus on
>   Pay particular attention to.
>   ‘the study will focus on a
>   number of areas in Wales’

[Focus (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/focus)

Comment: It’s interesting, though, how we generally focus **on** something, yet we generally stay **in focus**.

Comment: In focus, but on topic, and in UK politics at least, on message.